# What's the difference between node_modules\@firebase and node_modules\firebase packages?

Tags: firebase, webpack, code-splitting

I'm working on my code splitting logic and I want to split `firebase` chunks.

So I'm logging out the `module.context` on my `splitChunks` configuration on `webpack.config.ts`

**webpack.config.ts**

```
optimization: {
  ...,
  splitChunks: {
    chunks: "all",
    cacheGroups: {
     firebase: {
       test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/].*firebase/,
       name: (module: webpack.Module, chunks: webpack.Chunk[], cacheGroupKey: string) => {
         const { context } = module;
         console.log(context);
         return "firebase";
       }
     }
   }
 }
}
```

This what gets logged:

```
C:\PROJECT\node_modules\firebase\app\dist
C:\PROJECT\node_modules\firebase\auth\dist
C:\PROJECT\node_modules\firebase\firestore\dist
C:\PROJECT\node_modules\firebase\storage\dist
C:\PROJECT\node_modules\@firebase\auth\dist
C:\PROJECT\node_modules\@firebase\app\dist
C:\PROJECT\node_modules\@firebase\storage\dist
C:\PROJECT\node_modules\@firebase\firestore\dist\esm5
C:\PROJECT\node_modules\@firebase\firestore\dist\esm5
C:\PROJECT\node_modules\@firebase\util\dist
C:\PROJECT\node_modules\@firebase\component\dist
C:\PROJECT\node_modules\@firebase\logger\dist
C:\PROJECT\node_modules\@firebase\webchannel-wrapper\dist
```

What is the difference between the `node_modules\firebase` and the `node_modules\@firebase` packages?

Answer (score 2):

I came up with the same question while working with SvelteKit. Here's a piece to the puzzle that helped my build:

> It works but you have to change all "import {} from 'firebase/..'" to
> "import {} from '@firebase/..'". Internally the first import just does
> a "export * from '@firebase/..'".

For more info, see [this link](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/5140#issuecomment-877873040).

If my reading of the NPM docs is correct, node_modules@firebase/ is a [scoped package](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/scope) of node_modules/firebase/